# Customising Moodle login page

Tags: moodle

I want to customize the Moodle login page. That is why I want to change the keywords like "Username" to "uid" and also the keyword "password" to "Userpassword".

I'm using Moodle version: 2.7, theme: clean.

Suggest me some steps to make changes to those keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the language strings via the menu

site admin -> language -> language customisation -> choose a language -> search for the strings

Behind the scenes, this will create a local version in `moodledata/lang/`

eg: `moodledata/lang/en_local/moodle.php`

This is better than modifying the core code.

Or you could just create the above file directly and add the strings that need modifying eg;

```
<?php

// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/**
 * Local language pack from http://yourwebsite.com
 *
 * @package    core
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$string['password'] = 'Userpassword';
$string['username'] = 'uid';
```

Comment: i have added to the file but what to do for viewing the changes .i could not view any change.

Comment: Site admin > Developer > Purge all caches. This should load the changes you made (done automatically if you change the language strings via the system menu)

Comment: Oh yes the language strings will be cached - try going to site admin -> language settings -> and switch off langstringcache then try again. Remember to switch it back on after you have finished.

Comment: can you help me to solve the following issue.i have connected my moodle to apache directory studio  (ldap server) .i have dn as dn:uid=admin,ou=system and i have created two users i that .when i try to log on with that user's uid and userpassword i get "Invalid login" error.

Comment: what to do with this ? else suggest me some other methods to create new user

Comment: You might want to create that as a separate question.